# Unable to load data from a CSV file into HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, null, hdfs

I am getting 'None' values while loading data from a CSV file into hive external table.
My CSV file structure is like this:

```
creation_month,accts_created
7/1/2018,40847
6/1/2018,67216
5/1/2018,76009
4/1/2018,87611
3/1/2018,99687
2/1/2018,92631
1/1/2018,111951
12/1/2017,107717
```

'creation_month' and 'accts_created' are my column headers.

```
create external table monthly_creation
(creation_month DATE,
 accts_created INT
 )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' location '/user/dir4/'
```

The location is '/user/dir4/' because that's where I put the 'monthly_acct_creation.csv' file, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

I have no idea why the external table I created had all 'None' values when the source data have dates and numbers.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Hives default date format isn't MM/dd/yyyy format, and your file shouldn't have a header before loaded into HDFS

Comment: @cricket_007 .. the file can have a header and specifying the option `tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")` should take care of it.

Comment: @Vamsi Well, that's missing from the question

Comment: can you show the `load data...` statement being used?

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. Can HIVE load data from XLSX files as opposed to CSV? (Not sure if this matters but I am using Hortonworks Hadoop GUI to run the HIVE commands)

Comment: There is no "Hortonworks Hive GUI" - the tool you're using is called Hue, and actually developed by Cloudera. I don't use XSLX because it's not a "supported Hadoop file format" (plus Hadoop prefers files that are several GB or TB large, and you'll almost never see Excel files that large). That doesn't mean you can't use some Apache POI library for processing that data, it just won't be through Hive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DATE values describe a particular year/month/day, in the form YYYY-­MM-­DD. For example, DATE '2013-­01-­01'.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-date

I suggest using string type for your date column, which you can convert later or parse into timestamps.

Regarding the integer column, you'll need to skip the header for all columns to be appropriately converted to int types

---

By the way, new versions of HUE allow you to build Hive tables directly from CSV

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007! Your suggestion on making the 'creation_month' column string type and removing the column headers solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Date** data type format in hive only accepts **yyyy-MM-dd** as your date field is not in the same format and that results null values in creation_month field value.

Create table with **creation_month field as string datatype** and **skip the first line by using skip.header.line** property in create table statement.

> **Try with below ddl:**

```
hive> create external table monthly_creation
(creation_month string,
 accts_created INT
 )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
Location '/user/dir4/'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

hive> select * from monthly_creation;
+-----------------+----------------+--+
| creation_month  | accts_created  |
+-----------------+----------------+--+
| 7/1/2018        | 40847          |
| 6/1/2018        | 67216          |
| 5/1/2018        | 76009          |
| 4/1/2018        | 87611          |
| 3/1/2018        | 99687          |
| 2/1/2018        | 92631          |
| 1/1/2018        | 111951         |
| 12/1/2017       | 107717         |
+-----------------+----------------+--+
```

Comment: Thank you, @Shu! Your suggestion was very helpful in solving my problem.